# Moq does not return the value I set up

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, moq

I'm new to Moq. I'm trying to setup my Repository to return a value when called:

My test method:

```
 _userServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GetUserIDByUserName(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(2);
 _bidRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Match(It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Bid>, object>>(),
                        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Bid, object>>[]>())).Returns(new Bid{UserId = 2});
 var service = SetupService();
 var result = service.GetOwnBid(1, "testuser");
```

The userServiceMock returns 2 just as it should, but the bidRepositoryMock returns null.

The Method I'm unit testing looks like this:

```
  var bid = _bidRepository.Match(userBid => userBid.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == id),
                b => b.UserProfile,
                b => b.Task.UserProfile);
```

and the BidRepository Method Match Looks like this:

```
TResult Match<TResult>(Func<IQueryable<T>, TResult> query, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
```

Comment: What type will be returned by this method `userBid.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == id)`?

Comment: Oh. that might return an IQueryable<T> and not a Bid I suppose.

Comment: But why would Moq care? I don't quite understand this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this code from `It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Bid>, object>>()` to `It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Bid>, Bid>>()`

```
_bidRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Match(It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Bid>, Bid>>(),
                        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Bid, object>>[]>())).Returns(new Bid{UserId = 2});
```

Because you method returns the `TResult` type in your query it will be the `Bid` type.

Comment: My family just got home and I have to tend to two children. I'll check this out first thing tomorrow morning. Thank you